# Dividing an integral by a variable.

Tags: calculus, integration

In my lecture notes I got this:
$$\int_u^vdv = \int_0^T(-4v)dt$$
$$\int_u^v\frac {dv}v = -4\int_0^Tdt$$
$$ln{\frac vu} = -4T$$
Is the second step actually valid? I mean, can you divide an integral by upper limit of the integral on LHS?

Comment: This is a little confusing, because the two $v$'s on the left-hand side mean differemt things.  In the upper limit of integration, $v$ is some consatnt.  In $dv$, we can think of it as a dummy variable inside the integral, that we could replace by some other letter.  It would be clearer if the instructor had written the left-hand side as $\int_u^v\frac{\mathrm{dt}}{t}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would be valid is$$\int_u^vdv^\prime=\int_0^T(-4v)dt\implies v-u=-4vT,$$or $$\int_u^v\frac{dv^\prime}{v^\prime}=-4\int_0^Tdt\implies\ln\frac{v}{u}=-4T.$$But in your notes, something has gone wrong due to conflating a free variable $v$ with a bound variable I've denoted $v^\prime$. The latter is a dummy integration variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see that I simply took the upper limit written in notes as v instead of V.
The above is actually correctly written in the notes as:
$$\int_u^Vdv = \int_0^T(-4v)dt$$
$$\int_u^V\frac {dv}v = -4\int_0^Tdt$$
$$ln{\frac Vu} = -4T$$

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Whatever "$v$" is on the RHS, it can't be the integration variable on the LHS.